# Webdiyer.WebControls.Mvc.PagerHelper.AjaxPager failed to access security critical type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString'

Tags: model-view-controller

This Error shown after updating MVC to version 5.2.2.0.

Error:

Attempt by security transparent method

> Webdiyer.WebControls.Mvc.PagerHelper.AjaxPager(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, Webdiyer.WebControls.Mvc.IPagedList, Webdiyer.WebControls.Mvc.PagerOptions, System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions, System.Object)' to access security critical type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' failed.
>
> Assembly 'MvcPager, Version=1.5.0.28157, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when i updated my project to MVC 5.
I have removed existing MvcPager from my project (Uninsatll / remove manually).
I have installed latest MvcPager to my project from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Webdiyer.MvcPager/) .

There is a small change in Pager syntax, you can get the source code [here](http://en.webdiyer.com/mvcpager/demos/ajaxpaging).

After the changes it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

After updated our projects to MVC 5, we had the same issue. 
Remove MvcPager reference from all relevant projects. Add Webdiyer.MvcPager Version 3.0.1.1 in NuGet Package Manager.

In the cshtml, we had

```
@Html.AjaxPager(
                    Model,
                    new PagerOptions()
                    {
                        PageIndexParameterName = "id",
                        ShowDisabledPagerItems = false,
                        AlwaysShowFirstLastPageNumber = true,
                        ShowPageIndexBox = false,
                        AutoHide=true,
                        NumericPagerItemCount = 5,
                        ShowFirstLast=false,
                        ShowPrevNext =false
                    },
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "majorRow"
                    })
```

I changed it to

```
 @Ajax.Pager(
                    Model,
                    new PagerOptions()
                    {
                        PageIndexParameterName = "id",
                        ShowDisabledPagerItems = false,
                        AlwaysShowFirstLastPageNumber = true,
                        //ShowPageIndexBox = false,
                        AutoHide = true,
                        NumericPagerItemCount = 5,
                        ShowFirstLast = false,
                        ShowPrevNext = false
                    }).AjaxOptions(
                       a => a.SetUpdateTargetId("majorRow")
                    )
```

Then it works as before. No error anymore.